apache nifi 2.0 ListenHTTP component does not start anymore after being stopped
i have installed nifi 2.0 in linux ubuntu, i start my first process, when i add ListenHTTP, it start but after being stopped, the component does not start anymore

and if i send some http request they stay in the queue, What property should I change so that the messages in the queue are processed?

according to a screenshot ListenHttp working well, but the next processor has an issue - there is an exclamation sign - hover it and you should see some explanation.

also the queue between listenhttp and mergecontent is pretty small and seems it's full - so listenhttp can't push messages into it.

The MergeContent is done when i fix relationship. The start of th http listener is not working when i stop the listener by the

you have to provide more information what do you mean by "http listener is not working". otherwise there is no way to help you.

when i create the component at first time and start it, i can send http request with insomnia and get 200 return code. If i stop it and start. The icon of component is started, but with linux command there's no port opened to listen. And if i send request with insomnia i get error   https://i.postimg.cc/j5wF1mtV/image.png
